# Using regex to match strings with a given histogram (number of occurrence of certain characters in any order)

Tags: regex, grep

Is it possible to use regex to match string that have a certain number of occurrence of some characters?

For example, I would like to find all words that have 1 'a' and 2 'l'. So the following words would match: all, allow, tall, pallet, liability.

The example below would find only the patterns that have 1 'a' and 2 'l' in sequence, and not in any order and position on the string.

```
echo -e "all\nallow\ntall\npallet\nliability" | grep 'a\{1\}l\{2\}'
```

Comment: Regex is not particularly good at this. You would be better off using other tools.

Comment: When providing sample input for a comparison, it's much more useful to provide both some samples that do AND some that don't match. If you only provide input that does match then a script that tests for `.` will produce the expected output so that's not useful for testing a potential solution against.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'gsub(/a/,"&")==1 && gsub(/l/,"&")==2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

On engines with infinite look ahead this is supposed to work:

```
(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^l]*l[^l]*l).*
```

Explanation:

`(?=[^a]*a)` fails if there is no `a` in the string.

`(?=[^l]*l[^l]*l)` fails if there is no 2 `l` in the string.

`.*` matches the actual string.

But I'm not sure if `grep` supports this.